# How can add Account to "Apple Developer Accounts" in Visual Studio Xamarin Form?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I want to build project in IPhone 5 but 
one error: "could not find any available provisioning profiles"
I search in google they said add Account Developer then another error
like this:

Someone can help me please! thank you!

Comment: https://clearbridgemobile.com/how-to-create-a-distribution-provisioning-profile-for-ios/

Comment: I suggest you read this documentation to learn more about iOS provisioning.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/. And did you try to deploy it on another device?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Apple Dev Account. Go to [Apple dev site](https://developer.apple.com) and create an account. Next add this account to Apple developer accounts in VS in preferences -> publishing -> Apple developer accounts. And then you can run iOS app. 
Remember to set Automatic Provisioning in Info.plist in Signing section.

Comment: i did it. Exactly what you said. But Error always like picture I post in

Comment: sorry, i forgot upload picture error in here. Now I'm busy. Sorry i will upload when i come home. tks

Comment: I don't see any picture